# Int array vs Char array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    char ch[] = "sai";
    int a[] = {1,2,3};
    
    // statement : 1
    std::cout << ch << ' ' << a << '\n';

    // statement 2
    std::cout << *ch << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sai 0x7fff900919b8
s
```

expecting:

```
**address of first char** 0x7ffde5767cd8
s
```

**Reasoning:**

ch stores the address of the first character of the copy of string literal `sai`. So when we are printing ch then it should print the address right?

Whereas both statement-2 and int array `a` outputs are printed as expected.

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Operator `<<` of object `std::cout` is defined differently for `char` array.

In 99% of cases, you want to treat it as string literal, so instead of printing an address it prints string.